# Телеграм бот не отвечает на все вопросы

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Бот откликается на первые пару команд, а дальше будто не слышит меня. На "загадка 3" он будто выключается, в чём причина?

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def test(message):
    if message.chat.type=='private':
        if message.text == 'загадка 1':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
            "В синем небе светляки — Не дотянешь к ним руки. А один большой светляк Изогнулся, как червяк.")
        if message.text == 'загадка 2':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "Мягкое, легкое, а через дом не перекинуть.")
            if message.text == 'загадка 3':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что нужно поставить между 6 и 7, чтобы результат оказался меньше 7 и больше 6?")
                if message.text == 'загадка 4':
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Зимой и летом одним цветом.")
                else:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "не понимаю о чем вы")
```

[image]

Не понимаю в чем причина засыпания бота. Пробовал добавить конструкцию elif, всё тоже самое, только ошибок больше.

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно if расставлены

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def test(message):
    if message.chat.type=='private':
        if message.text == 'загадка 1':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
            "В синем небе светляки — Не дотянешь к ним руки. А один большой светляк Изогнулся, как червяк.")
        if message.text == 'загадка 2':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "Мягкое, легкое, а через дом не перекинуть.")
        if message.text == 'загадка 3':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что нужно поставить между 6 и 7, чтобы результат оказался меньше 7 и больше 6?")
        if message.text == 'загадка 4':
             bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Зимой и летом одним цветом.")
      else:
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "не понимаю о чем вы")
```